# Save custom price radio button value in cart and display it on Cart page Woocommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce

I have added custom price on woocommerce single product page using 
    the code below on my theme's functions php:

```
<?php
// Output the Custom field in Product pages
add_action("woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button", "options_on_single_product", 1);
function options_on_single_product(){
 ?>
<ul class="pricing-options">
<li>
<div class="custom-radio">
<input type="radio" id="opt1" class="" name="filter_opt" checked>
<label for="opt1" data-price="<?php echo wc_price( $price ) ;?>">
<span class="circle"></span>Single Site License </label>
</div>

<p>Nunc placerat mi id nisi interdum is mollis. Praesent pharetra, justo ut sceleris que
     the mattis, leo quam.</p>
</li>

<li>
<div class="custom-radio">
<input type="radio" id="opt2" class="" name="filter_opt">
<label for="opt2" data-price="<?php echo wc_price( $price*3 ) ;?>">
<span class="circle"></span>2 Sites License</label>
 </div>

<p>Nunc placerat mi id nisi interdum is mollis. Praesent pharetra, justo ut sceleris que
        the mattis, leo quam.</p>
</li>
</ul>
<?php
}
```

Now i want to display the selected option value on cart page. Please help me to do this. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
// Output the Custom field in Product pages
add_action("woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button", "options_on_single_product", 1);
function options_on_single_product(){
    ?>
        <label for="custom_field">
            <input type="radio" name="custom_field" checked="checked" value="option1"> option 1 <br />
            <input type="radio" name="custom_field" value="option2"> option 2
        </label> <br />
    <?php
}

// Stores the custom field value in Cart object
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'save_custom_product_field_data', 10, 2 );
function save_custom_product_field_data( $cart_item_data, $product_id ) {
    if( isset( $_REQUEST['custom_field'] ) ) {
        $cart_item_data[ 'custom_field' ] = $_REQUEST['custom_field'];
        // below statement make sure every add to cart action as unique line item
        $cart_item_data['unique_key'] = md5( microtime().rand() );
        WC()->session->set( 'my_order_data', $_REQUEST['custom_field'] );
    }
    return $cart_item_data;
}

// Outuput custom Item value in Cart and Checkout pages
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'output_custom_product_field_data', 10, 2 );
function output_custom_product_field_data( $cart_data, $cart_item ) {

    if( !empty( $cart_data ) )
        $custom_items = $cart_data;

    if( isset( $cart_item['custom_field'] ) ) {
        $custom_items[] = array(
            'key'       => __('Custom Item', 'woocommerce'),
            'value'     => $cart_item['custom_field'],
            'display'   => $cart_item['custom_field'],
        );
    }
    return $custom_items;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.

This code is tested and works.

Comment: Thanks .. i use the code it's work ...but the price not change in cart and cart page